# How is Schengen area revisited at end of six months?

Tags: schengen

As you may be aware, the Schengen visa area of Europe allows for Canadians to visit all of the countries under the Schengen treaty, without need for a visa, and for a period of 90 days out of any six month period.

I am a Canadian citizen currently visiting Spain.  In 2014, I entered the Schengen area in Paris, France, on October 25th.

As of April 25th 2015, it will be six months since my initial entry into the Schengen area.

As of April 25th 2015, my stay in the Schengen area will come to a total of approximately 70 days.

It is my intention to stay in the Schengen area beyond April 25th, if I am allowed to initiate a new six month period per the Schengen agreement.

My question is: am I allowed to initiate a new six month period without need to exit and re-enter the Schengen area?

Comment: So you have been in Schengen continuously since last October? You have already overstayed! If not, then there is some data missing from your question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The question says he's been in Schengen for just 70 days as of April 25th. Presumably, he returned to Canada at some point and then returned for a later trip which he'd like to have last beyond April 25th.

Answer (score 5):

The Schengen visa or the visa-free stay you get on entry as Canadian do not reset.
But at any day you can count back and should have been in the Schengen zone less than 90 days in the last 180 days.
If I counted right, you can stay on after April 25th, how many days depends on the distribution of the days in those first 180 days.
And do not forget that each part of a day counts, so if you leave 0:15 AM it counts as a full day and if you arrive just before midnight, that day counts as well.

Comment: (+1) The stamps do not “replace“ a visa, visa holders get them to. It's just that some people need a visa for short stays and others do not.

Comment: @Relaxed I changed the wording but am still not happy with it. Can you do better?

Comment: I tried something.

Comment: I like that better, I think it is legally right as well.